# Pandas: Drop rows with values less than today using np.where()?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

Given the following dataset, and current week as `2019/W37`, how do I drop rows that are previous to current week using `np.where`?

```
   Year  Week  Value
0  2019    31     10
1  2019    32     20
2  2019    33     30
3  2019    34     40
4  2019    35     50
5  2019    36     60
6  2019    37     70
7  2019    38     80
8  2019    39     90
9  2019    40    100
```

I tried the following:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

data = {
    "Year": [2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019, 2019],
    "Week": [31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37, 38, 39, 40],
    "Value": [10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

YearWeek = datetime.now().strftime("%Y/W%V")
print(YearWeek)

df["Exclude"] = np.where(str(df["Year"] + "/" + df["Week"]) < YearWeek, "Yes", "No")
print(df)
```

Comment: Why do you want to do this with np.where? also why do you need the specific string format? So far no answer has been addressing your specific requirements

Comment: I have used np.where across the script, since it is one of the fastest ways to loop through with conditions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
df_new = df[pd.to_datetime((df["Year"].astype(str) + "/W" + df["Week"].astype(str), format="%Y/W%V", errors='ignore') >= YearWeek]
```

or using np.where()

```
df.iloc[np.where(pd.to_datetime((df["Year"].astype(str) + "/W" + df["Week"].astype(str)), format="%Y/W%V", errors='ignore') >= YearWeek )]
```

To generate the exclude column:

```
df['exclude'] = np.where(pd.to_datetime((df["Year"].astype(str) + "/W" + df["Week"].astype(str)), format="%Y/W%V", errors='ignore') < YearWeek, 'Yes', 'No' )
```

Comment: Not sure why, but I am getting the following error - `numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'add' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U21'), dtype('<U21')) -> dtype('<U21')`

Comment: your times are imported as a int.on this particular df you will have to change df['year'] and df['Week'] to strings for this to work

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> print(df)
   Year  Week  Value
0  2019    31     10
1  2019    32     20
2  2019    33     30
3  2019    34     40
4  2019    35     50
5  2019    36     60
6  2019    37     70
7  2019    38     80
8  2019    39     90
9  2019    40    100
>>> today = pd.to_datetime('today')
>>> today
Timestamp('2019-09-12 22:54:46.039542')
>>> df[(df.Week < today.week) | (df.Year < today.year)]
   Year  Week  Value
0  2019    31     10
1  2019    32     20
2  2019    33     30
3  2019    34     40
4  2019    35     50
5  2019    36     60
```

Comment: After the OP's question, it must be  df[~(...)]

Comment: Should this be only `|` or `&` considering you will have today's date as, for eg, `01/03/2020`?

Answer (score 1):

You can use a decimal week system:

```
w = df['Year'] + df['Week'] / 54

now = pd.Timestamp.now()
this_week = now.year + now.week / 54

df[w >= this_week]
```

Result

```
   Year  Week  Value
6  2019    37     70
7  2019    38     80
8  2019    39     90
9  2019    40    100
```

In the [ISO Date System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date), a year can have up to 53 weeks so we use 54 to prevent the last week of year N appearing like year N+1. Anything over 54 works just as well. It's just a way for us to combine the year and the week into a single, comparable quantity.

Answer (score 1):

We can do

```
df[(df.Year*100+df.Week)<int(pd.to_datetime('today').strftime('%Y%W'))]
```